# Failed to show XML Data with PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have about 60000 xml files that i have to insert into a MySQL database. so i thought about making a simple php script that would be executed for once to load data from this xml files and insert it into my db on a localhost.

Before inserting it into my DB i tried to show them on the data on the page but it shows nothing, and its type is NULL.

here is the code :

```
<?php
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('organismes');
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
   if (!$fileinfo -> isDot()) {
         $XMLFILE = $fileinfo -> getFilename();
         echo $XMLFILE . "<br>\n"; /*the filename shows correctly, so the DirectoryIterator is working*/
         $pathtofile = "http://localhost/www/organismes/$XMLFILE"; /*the link to the xml file made with a variable*/
         echo $pathtofile . "<br>\n"; /* the link shown is correct */
         $xml = simplexml_load_file($pathtofile);
         echo gettype($xml) . "<br>\n";
         if ($xml == FALSE) {
                echo "failed to load xml"; /* this message never shows so the xml file   loads correctly */
         } else {
                $Org = $xml->Organisme->Nom; //this variable $Org gets a NULL Value
                echo $Org . "<br>" ;
                echo gettype($Org);
         }
   }
}
?>
```

when i used a print_r($xml), it shows some data so the file loads correctly.
and here is an example of the xml file that i have :

```
<Organisme id="adil-01053-01" codeInsee="01053" dateMiseAJour="2013-02-27" pivotLocal="adil">
<Nom>Agence</Nom>    
<EditeurSource>A2 A3</EditeurSource>
<Adresse type="géopostale">
<Ligne>34, rue du Général-Delestraint</Ligne>
<CodePostal>01000</CodePostal>
<NomCommune>Bourg-en-Bresse</NomCommune>
<Localisation>
<Latitude>46.196535</Latitude>
<Longitude>5.2191997</Longitude>
<Précision>6</Précision>
</Localisation>
<Accessibilité type="ACC"/></Adresse>
<CoordonnéesNum>
<Téléphone>00000000000</Téléphone>
<Télécopie>00000000000</Télécopie>
<Email>adil.01@wanadoo.fr</Email>
<Url>http://www.adil01.org</Url>
</CoordonnéesNum>
 <Ouverture><PlageJ début="vendredi" fin="vendredi"><PlageH début="09:00:00" fin="17:00:00"/></PlageJ><PlageJ début="lundi" fin="jeudi"><PlageH début="09:00:00" fin="18:00:00"/></PlageJ>
</Ouverture>
</Organisme>
```

so i am trying to figure it out why it doesn't show correctly and why it gets a NULL Value
So brothers if you can help that would be wonderful :)

Comment: Please do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your script. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log.

Comment: You get NULL if an element with such a name (here: `Nom`) does not exists. Use `echo $xml->asXML();` to output the XML verbatim and check where the elment you're looking for is actually placed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pathtofile = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($pathtofile);
if ($xml == FALSE) {
    echo "failed to load xml";
} 
else
{
    $A = $xml->to;
    echo "$A <br />";                       
}
```

Focusing on just that part of the code, it seems to work correctly. Either one of two things are happening. The "$xml->Organisme->Nom;" has a spelling error and/or the xml file being pulled does not include those field names.

For testing do

```
print_r($xml);
```

right after

```
echo "$A <br />";
```

to get an accurate representation of the xml file being pulled.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want but I assume you want to insert XML data into your database. If that's the case, try this:

```
function create_xml()
{


    $xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");



    $nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('file.xml', null, true)
             or die("cannot create");

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($nodes->children() as $child)
    {


             $var= $child->xml_child;


              $sql = "INSERT INTO ...)";

              mysqli_query($connect, $sql);


             $i++;

             echo "xml set";




    }


}
```

Comment: thank you marciano, as you said what i want is to insert the xml data in my db, butit insert only NULL Values, why that while the xml loads correctly ??

Comment: I GUESS that it is because the XML object hasn't any children.
You should add this: 

 $nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('file.xml', null, true)
    or die("cannot create");

And then do $nodes->Organisme->nom

Comment: i tried your method, and its not working too, it shows nothing, only NULL Values, and really i dont get it :D i cant figure it out, where is the problem, thank you any way :)

Comment: here is the part i added to my previews code : $nodes = new SimpleXMLElement($pathtofile, null, true)
             or die("cannot create");
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($nodes->children() as $child)
    {
             $var= $child->Organisme->Nom;
             echo $var. "<br>";

Comment: This should be working. Is your insertion code to the db correct? Did you use mysql_query or mysqli_query? And does printf($nodes) work?